# What are the possible means for showing that a timer is running?

Tags: buttons, time

Some button in my app is blocked until a timer finishes. But, I don't want to display the remaining time, so that the user does not keep staring at the timer, waiting for the button to be unblocked.

I am looking for a subtle way to indicate the user that a timer is running.

What are the possible means for doing that?

So far, I do this: the transparency of the button varies between 1 and 0.3 continuously, every 1 second.

Comment: why do you want it to be subtle and avoid displaying time?

Comment: Because the user needs to be doing something else during this time. The user should not keep staring at the timer.

Comment: Then you should add some context. remember, in UX *context is everything*

Comment: how about adding that standard circular animation on the button - pretty intuitive

Comment: Perhaps with a small node that pulses at 1sec intervals.

Comment: Lemme guess, the app is shareware/demoware/adware and displays a nag notice or an ad (video) for (at least) _n_ seconds during which the `continue` or `skip` button is blocked. Either way, I don’t see a good reason not to display a progress bar (or circle). Keeping the user in the dark on how long something will take, despite the software knowing it exactly, will always be bad UX. There are just different levels of badness.

Comment: I'd go with the "circular animation" answer.  Specifically a spinner in the button.  It avoids a timer (implying action required "later", not "at this time"), and, if colored correctly, won't draw the eye of the user.  I think the pulsing would be a bit overkill, as it would draw the user's eye to the element, which is not the intent.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an element that will avoid any assumption of "progress," I'd go with a spinner.  Best possibly placed to the left of the text in the button.

A spinner tells the user there will be action required "later," rather than "at this time," which, if it does draw the eye of the user, will only send their eyes back to the current intended focus.

Users are used to seeing a spinner for things like "Loading..." messages.  This tells the user "something will happen later, come back when you assume enough time has passed for the status to change."

Answer (score 0):

A Pre-loader animation would work. Like Wtfsven mentionen above a spinner, or any moving animation would work. In taxi meters i've seen animation of a horse running. Maybe a running man animation would work in your case
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the spinner because it is somehow means "A calculation is being done".

I tried "three dots" animating and I tried one dote pulsing.

But finally, what I chose is this: the button pulses between "0.3 opacity" and "1.0 opacity".

Answer (score 0):

#### Movement is the last thing you want…

Whether pulsating or rotating, all visual changes in the interface risk attracting the user's attention—and you've said they're supposed to be doing something else for the duration of this wait time. Why distract users by showing visual movement?

#### An alternative

**Before** the user clicks the button, show no wait feedback.

**After** the user clicks the button, if the wait time has elapsed, proceed. The user doesn't need to know that there was a wait time.,

**After** the user clicks the button, if there is more then 0.4 seconds of  remaining wait time, show the wait feedback then. The amount of wait time is a known quantity, so ensure the feedback shows that the wait time is finite—in the style of a progress-bar.

Here's a suggestion—but there are many other possible solutions. To signal that the wait is directly involved in delaying the button's action, combine the button and the progress-bar feedback:

[image: Progress-bar in a button]